# Can't get data.tree to work?

Tags: r, tree

I am trying the following code from data.tree examples

```
> data(acme)
> acme$Do(function(node) node$expectedCost <- node$p * node$cost)
> print(acme, "expectedCost")
```

but I am getting the below warning (converted to error). Can you please help here..

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, colName, value = list(`Acme Inc.` = numeric(0),  : 
(converted from warning) provided 11 variables to replace 1 variables

3: ToDataFrameTree(x, format = TRUE, ...)
2: print.Node(acme, "expectedCost")
1: print(acme, "expectedCost")
```

Comment: This was an error that was introduced by a change in a dependency. But I fixed it, and your example should work again with the latest data.tree version on CRAN 0.7.3

Comment: Thanks Chris for fixing this. Being new to data.tree, intention was not to ask a rhetoric question, but to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

You are traversing over all the nodes, including root nodes, where there is no cost. As per the data.tree documentation:

> cost, only available for leaf nodes. Cost of the project.

As such, the multiplication will not work. Thankfully, the filterFun parameter allows you to specify to apply the function to only leaf nodes, as below.

```
acme$Do( function( node ) node$expectedCost <- node$p * node$cost, filterFun = isLeaf )
```

You will now be able to print the expectedCost successfully.

Also note that the root nodes do not have a value for 'p'.

Comment: The example @ripatrao gave above is exactly the one given on the package pdf under the function Do.. Why would they give an example that produces errors?

Comment: @Onyambu: They would not do that on purpose. But they would prefer a bug report in github to a rhetorical question ;)